# Does @media with no arguments do anything?

Tags: css

I've inherited some code from a ... questionable ... web developer.  There are hundreds of style sheets referenced from each page of the site and each of them is riddled with extra @media tags that appear to be malformed.  They are just:

```
@media {
    /* A bunch of CSS rules */
}
@media {
    /* A bunch more CSS rules */
}
```

I'm trying to simplify the code base so that it will be easier for me to maintain.  My question is:  Is there any possible purpose at all in having @media by itself like that with no media type or media function arguments?

Comment: maybe to exclude ancient browsers who are not able to parse @media at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

> A media query is composed of an **optional media type** and **any number of media feature expressions**. Multiple queries can be combined in various ways by using logical operators. Media queries are case-insensitive.

Then

> Media types describe the general category of a device. Except when using the not or only logical operators, the media type is optional and the **all type will be implied.**

Basically you media query will apply to all devices whitout any restriction so technically you can omit the @media and you will have the same result.

Also [the support of @media](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution) is pretty good even for some old browsers so you should have the same result too.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to assume it was an @media support test added 10 years ago and remove it.  In my testing, it does in fact apply the rules to all the test cases I could come up with.